# Can I add an "Up" button to Files?

Tags: pantheon-files

In Luna, it was possible (using dconf) to add an "Up" button in Files, to move to the parent directory.

The same instructions don't work on Freya.

Is there a way to add an "Up" button to switch to the parent directory ?

Answer (score 7):

With the move to headerbar, toolbar customization was dropped. This gsettings key no longer has any affect.

To move up a directory, you can click the next directory up in the breadcrumb bar.

You can also use the shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>

Comment: Not a good news but at least that's an answer.
A shame there's no doc about the shortcut in general and for PatheonFiles in particular as there's no menu, there's no way to know the shortcuts.
I guessed the use of CTRL+1 CTRL+2 ...